# How to populate sql query result in a series of chained select boxes?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have these four tables (which are hierarchical, meanwhile) in my database:

Table 1: State

```
+----------+-------------+
| state_id | state_name  |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | Maharashtra |
|        2 | Goa         |
+----------+-------------+
```

Table 2: District

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| district_id | district_name | state_id |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
|           1 | Mumbai        |        1 |
|           2 | Pune          |        1 |
|           3 | Nashik        |        1 |
|           4 | Aurangabad    |        1 |
|           5 | Panjim        |        2 |
|           6 | Dandeli       |        2 |
|           7 | Karwar        |        2 |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

Table 3: Taluka

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| taluka_id | taluka_name | district_id |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|         1 | Alibag      |           1 |
|         2 | Kalyan      |           1 |
|         3 | Matheran    |           1 |
|         4 | Vaijapur    |           4 |
|         5 | Gangapur    |           4 |
|         6 | Kannad      |           4 |
|         7 | Sillod      |           4 |
|         8 | Madgaon     |           5 |
|         9 | Vengurle    |           5 |
|        10 | Sawantwadi  |           5 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Table 4: Village

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+
| village_id | village_name | taluka_id |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
|          1 | Ranjangaon   |         5 |
|          2 | Wadgaon      |         5 |
|          3 | Teesgaon     |         5 |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

How could I show select boxes dynamically loaded while happening of following events:

- Display select box for state names from "State" table

  - Here, `state_id` as value of `<option>` tag and `state_name` as text between opening and closing `<option>` tags)
- On selecting any of the state from first select box for states, display a newly created select box for district names from "District" table relative to selected state option from first select box

  - Here, `district_id` as value of `<option>` tag and `district_name` as text between opening and closing `<option>` tags
- Similary create a new select box for Talukas under selected District from second select box.
- Once again, similary create a new select box for Villages under selected Taluka from third select box.

---

In the above manner, when going through selecting one by one values from newly created select boxes (which we may call children of parent/root select boxes), we finally would have four select boxes for viz. State, District, Taluka, Village.

The aim behind this process is that I need to get the `village_id` of specific Village along with other data like it's `state_id`, `district_id`, and `taluka_id`.

Please provide an easy to use and flexible solution strictly using **jQuery + AJAX, MySQL, PHP**.

FYI, I have succeeded to populate select boxes for States and Districts using jQuery's ajax method to POST value of changed select box asynchronously to a query containing PHP script. Well, this worked until I get second select box for Districts. This select box for Districts is created by DOM manipulation rather by server using jQuery, so I couldn't check for `change` event on Districts' select box so as to POST it's selected value via AJAX to a MySQL query containing PHP script which queries Database for specific District and returns relative Talukas. Can it be handled using `bind`, `delegate` or `live` event handlers, huh--I don't know!!! :P

---

Well, my logic must be totally wrong. Just forget it, and please give me a complete solution. I will learn many things from that solution.
Thank you for reading this all disgust, by the way! ;)

---

I have created a prototype design for this. This should help to describe the question in visual way (or exactly what I wanted as output or solution to be):

[image: "Prototype design for describing question"]

---

---

**UPDATE**: Working demo code is available here: https://github.com/vishaltelangre/select-chain

Comment: NEVER trust the client-side to build up SQL strings unless you like your DB to be hacked via SQL Injection.

Comment: Yes, I agree too. Although it is controlled by parsing the passed $_GET or $_POST values from client-side application in server-side PHP script by the use of PHP functions like trim(), mysql_real_escape_string() and others of similar kind. But it doesn't prevent SQL injections at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Show a dropdown using `State` table. `state_id` will be option value and `state_name` will be text.
2. When `onchange` event fires on this dropdown get the value of *selected option*.
3. Send an Ajax call to load district for selected state. The parameter will be `state_id`
4. In the PHP end get all the rows from `District` that with matching `state_id`. Return it as JSON response
5. When Ajax get the response, create a new dropdown or populate previously created one with this new result.
6. Go to Step 1 for `District` then `Taluka` then `Village`